# What is the formula for conversion ratio?

Tags: math

I got a simple math problem.I am trying the find the conversion ratio between two symbol.Let assume that

> A : B
>
> 1 : 100 (1 A = 100 B)
>
> B : C
>
> 1 : ? (1 B = ? C)
>
> A : C
>
> 1 : 300 (1 A = 300 C)

What is the C equivalent of 1 B? and what is the formula used to calculate such problem?

Comment: Not the right site for Math problems. Have you tried Mathematics SE? <a href = "http://math.stackexchange.com"> Math SE </a>

Comment: I know now that there is different SE for Mathematics. I will post other math question there. Thank for informing me.

Comment: Np! Glad I could help ;).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Comment: I agree with your vote. I admit that I posted in wrong section.

Answer (score 0):

```
A:C = A:B X B:C = 1:100 X 1:200 = 1:20000
```

Does this make sense to you? Or you need more explanation?

Comment: It make sense when you put it that way.

Could I make the assumption below?

r = (C ratio of B X C ratio of A)

A value X r = A value of C

Comment: Sorry could you please rearrange statement `r = (C ratio of B X C ratio of A) A value X r = A value of C`

Comment: Sorry I do not know how to rearrange

Comment: You are almost right. Correction statement would be : `r = (C ratio of B X B ratio of A)` and then `A value X r = A value of C`

Comment: Sorry,It's look like I confuse the question myself. I have edit the question.

Comment: Ok fine. So my answer was somewhat useful to you :)

Comment: ,Thank. I still need to know r value, maybe I will just ask in Mathematics SE.